# Is --supported-target-version a supported option for mkinitramfs, as shown on the man page?

Tags: 18.04, initramfs, manpage

I am trying to the `--supported-target-version` option for `mkinitramfs`.  The following errors are being returned:

```
$ sudo mkinitramfs --supported-target-version=4.13.0-15-generic
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: unrecognized option '--supported-target-version=4.13.0-15-generic'
W: non-GNU getopt

$ sudo mkinitramfs --supported-target-version=/etc/boot-backup-ub16/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: unrecognized option '--supported-target-version=/etc/boot-backup-ub16/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic'
W: non-GNU getopt
```

According to 18.04 `mkinitramfs` man page `--supported-target-version` is supported.

Am I using this wrong or is `--supported-target-version` really not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not. These options were [removed over a decade ago](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/commit/e0cf94677002f7dd2d427ce0ebfe9412b2e45c47). The manpage was only [fixed a month ago](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/commit/b8d3d5968cfb93e4db22057c3eef143a154ded6f).